# MYSQL Query: group by entries per date and count entries

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have two columns, a timestamp and a number which card has been selected.

```
card      added
1         2016-09-23 13:48:48
3         2016-09-23 13:48:48
1         2016-09-23 13:48:48
2         2016-09-24 13:48:48
1         2016-09-24 13:48:48
2         2016-09-24 13:48:48
3         2016-09-24 13:48:48
```

What I need as an output is the count of each card, grouped by entry, like this:

```
card      count     added
1         2         2016-09-23
3         1         2016-09-23
1         1         2016-09-24
2         2         2016-09-24
3         1         2016-09-24
```

So I think I have to count card where added is the same. But I don't know how to, plus I need it to be grouped by card per added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group your results by the card and truncated date. The truncation can be done by calling [`date()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

```
SELECT   card, DATE(added) AS added, COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY card, DATE(added)
```

Comment: This was way easier than I thought. Thank you very much. Didn't know I could group by two cols

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `GROUP BY` the card and date:

```
SELECT card, COUNT(*), CAST(added AS date) added
FROM your_table
GROUP BY card, CAST(added AS date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT card, COUNT(card) AS CNT, added
FROM `example_table`
GROUP BY card, added
ORDER BY added ASC, card ASC
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to add an explanation on what your code does. This allows newer developers to understand how the code works.

Comment: Yes is true, sorry. My fault.
I wrote a salutation before the query but when selected the code formatter it disappeared, then I saw so many answers were published while I was writing mine and assumed it was already solved.